# How to implement CRUD operations in Andriod Studio app

Tags: android

I've been trying to complete an app for one of my courses, but I cannot seem to figure out the error in this tutorial. I believe the error is in this last Java class that implements the add, delete, and search features for the app. I had to change a line of the import statements from import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; to import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; However, the code is still not working. Any input would be helpful.

```
package cs360.com.databaseexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatabaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView idView;
    EditText nameBox;
    EditText ageBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        idView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dogID);
        nameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dogName);
        ageBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dogAge);
    }

    public void newDog(View view) {
        DogDBHandler dbHandler = new DogDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageBox.getText().toString());
        Dog dog = new Dog(age, nameBox.getText().toString());

        dbHandler.addDog(dog);
        nameBox.setText("");
        ageBox.setText("");
    }

    public void searchForDog(View view) {
        DogDBHandler dbHandler = new DogDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        Dog dog = dbHandler.searchDog(nameBox.getText().toString());

        if (dog != null) {
            idView.setText(String.valueOf(dog.getID()));
            ageBox.setText(String.valueOf(dog.getAge()));
        } else {
            idView.setText("Dog not found.");
        }
    }

    public void deleteDog(View view) {
        DogDBHandler dbHandler = new DogDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        boolean result = dbHandler.deleteDog(nameBox.getText().toString());

        if (result)
        {
            idView.setText("Dog Deleted");
            nameBox.setText("");
            ageBox.setText("");
        } else {
            idView.setText("Dog not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you get when you try to run the app? the issue happens while compiling or running?

Comment: @Tracy Harrison, is your problem solved or is it still persisting?

Answer (score 1):

> I had to change a line of the import statements from import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; to import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

From this, I think it's a problem related to the Migration to AndroidX. With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, Select `Refactor` > `Migrate to AndroidX` from the menu bar. Then , check your `gradle.properties` file and add the follwing if it's not there:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Please follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) for information on how to migrate to AndroidX. And if still any error persists, please perform a manual replace by Edit > Find > Replace in Path (CTRL+SHIFT+R) and follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings#androidsupportv7) to replace the old ones. For example, `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` to `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`. You'll find all the mappings to new AndroidX here.